# Can I add a 20A breaker to this electrical panel

Tags: current, amperage, circuit-breaker, panel

I replaced the oven at my small condo (600 sqft). Oven is 2300 watts/ 9.5 A. It needs a 20A breaker. The panel has a few empty slots.

Question: What's the best way to confirm that the panel can handle this addition? The panel says 125A. I manually added up all the appliance amperage ratings and it totals to 120A.

The general rule of thumb is to keep it at 80% of max (80% x 125) so 100A. But some electricians I spoke with say its completely fine to go a little over since its a home and there's never a situation where all the appliances are drawing at max load simultaneously.

Edit: Country is Canada.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SamuraiJack - Hi, Practical home mains wiring questions (as could be asked to an electrical contractor / electrician) should be posted at [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com) where they are [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). || Due to some people not engaging with questions after migration, causing wasted time on the destination site and then blaming us for doing the migration, I'm not going to migrate this question. Instead, as I see you have an account there, I recommend you repost the question on that site and include a photo of the panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Decision should be made based on rules from electrical code, not some electricians opinion. For calculating total load should be taken in account whole dwelling. If result, includes additional load does not exceed the maximum, you can add it. Maximum usually defined by capacity of main feeder, not main breaker in panel. Check the meter.

Comment: Assuming this is the US, based on phrasing, the usual code terminology to be looking for is the NEC standard load calculation. That should find the appropriate form.

Comment: @user1937198 your assumption may be wrong, OP did not mention the country. You may request for additional information.

Comment: They mentioned the word condo. How many other countries use that word? Also, I acknowledge its only a likely scenario rather than a definite, which is why I put it in a comment. If they are, its useful. If they aren't I've qualified it as US specific and its just noise.

Comment: @user1937198 Canada, etc.

Comment: @user1937198 this is Canada. Google says the equivalent here is CEC. I'm looking it up, thanks. If you have more specific guidelines, please share. The code book will likely have several sections, I'm looking for help on which section to narrow down to.

Comment: Thyis question would be better on the DIY/Home Improvement section - there appear to be lots of people there familiar with Electrical Codes and home wiring.